# Building Boost library

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, boost, bjam, boost-build

The problem is I have two versions of Visual Studio (VS 2008 and VS 2012) installed on my PC. I want to build Boost library *.lib  files for the older one. Unfortunately bjam.exe automatically compiles binaries for VS 2012. How to change the predefinition of native Visual version?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add [`--toolset=msvc-9.0` option](http://www.boost.org/boost-build2/doc/html/bbv2/reference/tools.html#bbv2.reference.tools.compiler.msvc).